# why my vim status line has a left red space

Tags: vim, powerline

I use vim and power-line plugin, but I found my vim status line has a ugly red space in the left. who can help me to remove the red space.

[image]

Comment: What value do you get when you run `:set statusline?`?

Comment: I get this: `statusline=%!Pl#Statusline(0,1)`

Comment: You may be overwriting `statusline` in your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: What is your statusline configuration? What plugins are you using?

Comment: `Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'`
`Plugin 'lokaltog/vim-powerline'`

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are using [the deprecated](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1745) (Lokaltog/vim-powerline) version of powerline as well as the system-wide version installed using pip globally in order to use it outside of vim.

In that case powerline [docs](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/other.html#vim-statusline) say that you need to only use the global powerline version and so you need to add the following line to your .vimrc:

```
python from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python powerline_setup()
python del powerline_setup
```